# How can I rehydrate a dried navel orange?

Tags: fruit, spoilage, dry-aging

I have a lot of navel oranges which are slightly dry inside. Is there a way to rehydrate these? How?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing I know of will make them juicy to eat on their own. Likely they were under-watered or picked late.

Can infuse with alcohol -inject or marinate- and have cocktails.

Or find a compote recipe. Peel still good.

I have tried adding a bit a water to cut halves to 'rinse out' more flavor when juicing but it was not worth the effort.